# Constant vs. Mutable iterators: same algorithm different code

Tags: c++, iteration, constants, mutable, visitor-pattern

My question involves how to reuse code, for an algorithm, that is `const` unaware (can be used with constant or mutable objects)?

Let's take for example the `std::vector` iterators.
There are two iterators classes that share similar methods:  `std::vector::iterator` and `std::vector::const_iterator`.

Both iterators point to *slots* in the vector or outside the vector (such as `std::vector::end()`).
They both have increment and decrement methods.
The primary difference is that the `const_iterator` cannot be used for writing to the the vector.

If I were writing the code for iterators, how could I have the `iterator` and `const_iterator` share methods that are not dependent on the constness of the access operation?

In my present code, I am duplicating the code for `for_each` and `visit` methods, because of the difference in accesibility.  The `for_each` loop is the same `for` loop the difference being the one applies a const_visitor and the other applies a mutable_visitor.

```
struct Object;

struct Const_Visitor
{
  // Visit function cannot modified the given object.
  virtual void visit(const Object& o) = 0;
};

struct Mutable_Visitor
{
  // The visit function may modify the given object;
  virtual void visit(Object& o) = 0;
};

struct Container
{
  const unsigned int LIMIT = 16;
  Object obj_container[LIMIT];

  // Apply the read-only (constant) visitor
  // to each object in the container
  void for_each(Const_Visitor& cv) const
  {
    // Note:  this loop management is the same
    // as the loop management for the mutable for_each() method.
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i)
    {
      cv.visit(obj_container[i]);
    }
  }


  // Apply the read/write (mutable) visitor
  // to each object in the container.
  void for_each(Mutable_Visitor& mv)
  {
    // Note:  this loop management is the same
    // as the loop management for the const for_each() method.
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i)
    {
      mv.visit(obj_container[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

In the above example, the mechanics are the same for both `for_each` functions.  Only the visitor changes. The same slots in the array are being passed to the `visit` functions.

This could be changed slightly by using one visitor with two `visit` methods, but the fundamental issue still exists.

```
struct Object;

struct Single_Visitor
{
  // Method can't modify the object.
  virtual void visit(const Object& o) = 0;

  // Method may modify the object.
  virtual void visit(Object& o) = 0;
};

struct Container
{
  const unsigned int LIMIT = 16;
  Object obj_container[LIMIT];

  // Apply a visitor to each item in container.
  void for_each(Single_Visitor& sv) const
  {
    for (unsigned int i; i < LIMIT; ++i)
    {
      // Should call the visit method,
      // constant object.
      sv.visit(obj_container[i]);
    }
  }


  // Apply a visitor to each item in container.
  void for_each(Single_Visitor& sv)
  {
    for (unsigned int i; i < LIMIT; ++i)
    {
      // Should call the visit method,
      //   mutable object.
      sv.visit(obj_container[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

With a visitor class that has two methods (vs. two separate classes), the container's `for_each` methods still have the same mechanics.  The looping is the same, just a different method is called.

So, is there a way to have one `for_each` loop that calls the appropriate visitor base on const-ness?

Comment: *"The primary difference is that the `const_iterator` cannot be used for writing to the the vector."* I'm not sure if that's relevant, but I think the proper description is that their value type is const-qualified. They could have mutable members etc.

Comment: Does this template solution look satisfying? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e81a4a86c4bf0453

Comment: I think the issue is one of the issues with visitors mentioned here: [cppcon 2014: accept no visitors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhJguzpZOrk). The underlying issue might be unrelated to iterators and visitors though; it's about having to write duplicate code for member functions due to the const-ness (and value category) of the class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have a single non-static member function that can work as either const or non-const. Instead, you can use non-member or static function template with container passed as an argument.

```
struct Container
{
  Object obj_container[LIMIT];

  // C can match either `const Container` or `Container`
  // V can match either `Const_Visitor` or `Mutable_Visitor`
  template<class C, class V>
  static void for_each(C& c, V& v) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i)
    {
      v.visit(c.obj_container[i]);
    }
  }

  void for_each(Const_Visitor& cv) const
  {
    for_each(*this, cv);
  }

  void for_each(Mutable_Visitor& mv)
  {
    for_each(*this, mv);
  }
};
```

Comment: If you define it as a friend function, it can even be called easily from the outside (if you don't like member functions ;) -- though this requires ADL tricks if both the member and non-member function shall have the same name.